# Calling 'unique' inline produces `Unknown or uninitialised column`, but calling the same function in the console produces desired results

Tags: r, excel, r-markdown, readxl

I have an excel sheet that I imported and assigned a new header using:

```
new_header <- read_excel("master.xlsx","sheet",n_max=0) %>%
  names()

sheet1 <- read_excel("master.xlsx","sheet", skip=2, col_names=new_header)
```

`sheet1` looks fine. But then, when I try to extract unique values from one of my columns, it doesn't work inline, **but works when called in the console**.

Example:

When I call the `unique(sheet1$name)` **inline**, I receive:

```
Unknown or uninitialised column: `name`.NULL
```

However, when I call the exact same code **in the console**, I receive a list with my desired values.

I don't understand how the same code written in in the console would not work inline... also I am using a markdown file to do this.

Answer (score 0):

While I still can't figure out why my script worked in the console and not inline, I applied a `.name_repair = universal` to my sheet, after which calling my columns worked fine inline.